# Trying to update the contact field from task field when task is create

Tags: trigger

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Task(after insert) { //You want it on update too, right?
  Map<ID, Contact> parentOpps = new Map<ID, Contact>(); //Making it a map instead of list for easier lookup
  List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

  for(Task childObj : Trigger.new) {
    listIds.add(childObj.whoID);
  }

  parentOpps = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT id, ISO__c,(SELECT ID, Inside_Sales_Reps__c FROM Task) FROM Contact WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

  for (Task tsk: Trigger.new){
     Contact myParentOpp = parentOpps.get(tsk.whoID);
     myParentOpp.ISO__c = tsk.Inside_Sales_Reps__c;
  }

  update parentOpps.values();
}
```

Comment: put a comma after the 'amount' in your soql query

Comment: geeting error after edit the code:
ID, Inside_Sales_Reps__c FROM Task) FROM Contact WHERE ID IN :listIds
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:57
Didn't understand relationship 'Task' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this error mean - you are missing a 'comma' in the SOQL Query , if you keenly notice there is one comma ' , ' was missed. This should fix the problem. Please put comma after amount and it should solve your problem. Here are the changes.

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Task(after insert) { //You want it on update too, right?
  Map<ID, Contact> parentOpps = new Map<ID, Contact>(); //Making it a map instead of list for easier lookup
  List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

  for(Task childObj : Trigger.new) {
    listIds.add(childObj.whoID);
  }

  parentOpps = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT id, amount, Name,(SELECT ID, Total_List_Price__c FROM Tasks) FROM Contact WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

  for (Task tsk: Trigger.new){
     Contact myParentOpp = parentOpps.get(tsk.whoID);
     myParentOpp.ISO__c = tsk.Inside_Sales_Reps__c;
  }

  update parentOpps.values();
}
```

Comment: but i have update the above code:getting different error :
ID, Inside_Sales_Reps__c FROM Task) FROM Contact WHERE ID IN :listIds
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:57
Didn't understand relationship 'Task' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: It should be Tasks in inner query not Task, edited my answer please have a look and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory. You're not using correct relationship name for querying `Task`. Instead of `Task`, use `Tasks`.

Refer below picture for reference:

[image]